# Add downward-pointing arrow in table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a way to implement the bottom arrow like in Apple's Activity app.

[image: Screenshots of iOS activity app showing downward-pointing chevron in cells]

I couldn't find anything similar in cell accessory type.

```
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.detailDisclosureButton
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.detailButton
```

I know that I can insert a `UIImage` there but maybe there's a better solution for this problem. I am using the default disclosure indicator in other cells, so I want to keep the same design in my app.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is adding a custom image asset and placing a UIImage in the cell's `accessoryView`.

A hacky solution -- that might not work -- that you could try would be to set the `accessoryType` to `disclosureIndicator` then try rotating the `accessoryView` by setting its `transform` to `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)`.

Comment: myCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
myCell..accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2) , this doesn't work. I have no idea but when i try to print acessoryView bounds i get nil

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rotate the default `disclosureIndicator`.

Here comes the regular solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil) // dequeue as necessary
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    let downArrow = UIImage(named: "down_arrow")
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: downArrow)
    return cell
}
```

[image]

White down arrow image at the end of this sentence.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the another solution. One more thing , do u know what size is accesoryType?

Comment: Not sure, probably need to adjust it until it feels right